Input loses focus when Popover opens in ShadCN
This component contains Popover & Input from shadcn. The issue I'm facing is that when I click on the Input to open the Popover, the Input loses focus, and the cursor moves out.
Expected behavior: 
When clicking on the Input component, the Popover should open, and the Input should remain focused with the cursor inside it, allowing the user to type without any additional clicks.
Link to Sandbox
"use client";

import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";

export default function Searchbar() {
  return (
    <div className="w-1/3">
      <Popover>
        <PopoverTrigger>
          <Input />
        </PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent>Place content for the popover here.</PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}


You can fix this like so:
<Popover>
  <PopoverTrigger>
    <Input />
  </PopoverTrigger>
  <PopoverContent onOpenAutoFocus={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
    Place content for the popover here.
  </PopoverContent>
</Popover>

Shadcn's <Popover /> uses Radix UI under the hood. The Radix docs for <Popover /> tell you how to prevent the popover from being focused, but it's not apparent. You have to hover the little "i" icon next to onOpenAutoFocus to see that you need to call preventDefault on the event. In my opinion, a section in their docs dedicated to this would be more helpful than hiding it behind a tooltip.
Here is a working example.

Rico's answer is correct! To add more context by default a11y rule, Popover is meant to be focused when opened because it usually contains an interactive component. If you want it to not "stealing the focus" with proper accessibility, maybe consider using Tooltip or HoverCard.

DImitrij, Thanks for the reply
I'm planning to use this component to implement a Twitter or Google-like search bar.
Here's my plan:
When the user focuses on the input field, the popover should open, displaying the old search history along with any new matching searches below. Additionally, when the user clicks out of the input field or the popover, the popover should close and lose focus.
Is there any other recommended way to achieve this?

There is a problem with the input field with the spacebar key. Inside the input field, when you use the space bar, the input field loses focus and the popover gets closed.
See the documentation radixui-popover-keyboard-interactions
